# Eclipse autocomplete irritation

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete

I seem to frequently trip over a particular "feature" of Eclipse's autocomplete behavior. Say that I'm programming in Java and start to code a method call like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    thing.
```

When I type the `.`, Eclipse pops up a list of candidate methods for `thing`. Suppose I select `method(int index)`. Eclipse inserts my choice:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    thing.method(index)
```

It also highlights `index` and pops up a list of variables I might want to use. The first item on the list is `index` and the second one is `i`. Not wanting to move my hands from the keyboard, I type `i`.

The problem is, I then out of habit usually press `enter` to complete the autocompletion sequence. Unfortunately, this causes Eclipse to select the first item on the suggestion list that starts with `i`, which is `index`. Argh! To avoid this, I need to either:

1. remember to press `tab` instead of `enter` after typing `i`;
2. select `i` from the suggestion list instead of typing it;
3. press `esc` (twice!) to get rid of the suggestion list before pressing `enter`.

With all of these, I'm forced to interrupt my thinking about my code in order to think about how to use Eclipse.

I realize that this is a long-winded rant for a fairly niggling problem, but I do actually have a question. Are there any settings in Eclipse (short of turning off autocompletion, which is otherwise very helpful) to either (1) tell it to rank legal options above illegal ones in the suggestion list or (2) otherwise tell Eclipse that when I type an `i`, that's what I want?

Comment: You could get used to using space instead of hitting enter. When i use eclipse I have to wait for a second before the auto suggest kicks in, that's enough time for me to have typed i and moved on without the auto complete problem. Have to set the auto suggest to immediate?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In the  'Java -> Editor -> Content Assist' preference page set 'Fill method arguments and show guessed arguments' to 'Insert best guessed arguments'

[image: Preference page]

Comment: Perfect! I don't know how I missed that.

Comment: It's a correctly worded, although a bit obscure. Beats me why it's not the default though.

Comment: You made my afternoon so much better.  Now if I could only figure out how to get it to suggest Boxed parameters (Integer for int)