# QString vs qstring.h

Tags: c++, qt, eclipse-cdt

I finally got C++/QT projects in Eclipse working. But when I try to include e.g. QString I get only qstring.h offered in code completion, typing QString manually works though.

I checked the QString file which simply includes qstring.h itself. But what is the reason for having such a file at all and not using qstring.h directly in the includes?

Additionally is it possible to get the QString in the code completion of Eclipse as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just a matter of taste. Here is a huge discussion about this: [Is having C++ header files without extension a good practice?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/135683/is-having-c-header-files-without-extension-a-good-practice)

For the next question, see this Eclipse bug: [Include file completion ignores files without file extension](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=292229) It seems that there is a solution provided on this page.

Answer (score 2):

> But what is the reason for having such a file at all and not using qstring.h directly in the includes?

Because this way they can move qstring.h anywhere they want while restructuring their code (for the next release, etc). They could also split headers into several, if they wanted, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

`include <QString>` should do it.

Why eclipse? QT Creator just sort of works.

You also got to think about the compiler you are using, I think QT has a wrapper for the visual studio compiler on windows. This probably comes into play as well.

Comment: I know that typing it by hand works, I'm just wondering why there is this QString construct around qstring.h.

Eclipse because I want to see what others have to offer, QtCreator is nice, but in some aspects also limited...

Comment: maybe this will point you in the right direction for configuring this. I would say its a case sensitivity glitch on the way the editor loads in all the symbols. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145241/eclipse-autocomplete-irritation