# Eclipse:Is there a shortcut key to realize the function of "Fill method arguments and show guessed arguments"

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

As we can see in the picture, when we invoke a method by the help of content assist, the feature of **"Fill method arguments and show guessed arguments"** will work.

[image: invoke a method]
[image: Fill method arguments]

I know this feature can be turn on/off in the Eclipse preference. Related question:[Eclipse autocomplete irritation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145241/eclipse-autocomplete-irritation/6145342#6145342).

My problem is here:**Is there a shortcut key to realize the same function?** In case sometime I may type a method by myself or change a typed argument. It will be more convenient if I had a way to **use this function manually**.

Comment: I cant see any images btw

Comment: The frist picture is "invoking a method by the help of content assist", It means select a method and press enter after pressing ".". After doing that, the method will be completed and some possible arguments will be listed in a yellow label, including several local variables. Is my message clear?

Answer (score 0):

`ctrl+space` is what you are looking for if I got your question right.

Comment: You mean the Content Assistant? I have tried but you can find that it will not list guessed arguments, it just offer related arguments after you typing the first letter of a argument. When the cursor is in brackets, if you typed nothing and press ctrl+space it will list possible methods. That's not exactly what I want, but still thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With `ctrl+shift+l` you can visualize a list of all available shortcuts. There you'll find the shortcut to Content Assistant is `ctrl+space`.
Another one, somewhat similar to what you were asking is `alt+/` for word completion

Comment: Yeah, I found that only if you press the first letter of a variable would these two features work.The Content Assistant would list some possible variables, the word completion will complete the variable immediately. They are not exactly what I want. Reminding the first letter of a variable is not as convenient as selecting a variable from a list, right? Thank you   for your attention.